# Using VBS Scripting.FileSystemObject won't work to find folders or files with certain diacriticals

Tags: vbscript, ascii, filesystemobject

The challenge is that I need to detect if a folder exists that can contain (in this case) Latvian language characters.  For example they can contain letters like ā š ņ.

Example:

```
Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
MsgBox fso.FolderExists("C:\Tests\āšņ")
```

Has no problem with French (àâêîôûùëïüÿ), but Latvian has ķ, ļ, ņ  - with 'commas' under the letter. These fail.

Wikipedia says:

> Windows-1257 (Windows Baltic) is an 8-bit, single-byte extended ASCII code page used to support the Estonian, Latvian and Lithuanian languages under Microsoft Windows. In Lithuania, it is standardised as LST 1590-3, alongside a modified variant named LST 1590-4.

Nice to know, but can that be applied somehow to FSO?

Comment: For Unicode support, make sure the VBScript is saved as Unicode (UTF-16) then using the command line execute the script with `cscript -u "path\to\script.vbs"`.

Comment: Just saving the script as  Unicode (UTF-16) appears to be enough.